# pulling data from a plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

I'm trying to pull some data from plist file and display it in a text field (from a UIButton click). the code below pulls the address of the plist and not the data. any help is greatly appreciated. thanks

```
-(IBAction) buttonPress {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"messages" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    [myMessage setText:path];
}
```

Comment: i'm also getting a warning message: "unused variable array"

Comment: Are you surprised that you get the warning about array being unused? If you look at the code, do you actually use it anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, you're printing out the path, not any item in the array. Change

```
[myMessage setText:path];
```

to

```
[myMessage setText:[array objectAtIndex:x]; //x = whatever index in the array contains your string.
```

Also you can change your plist to contain a dict and not an array so you could call specific text -

```
-(IBAction) buttonPress {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"messages" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    [myMessage setText:[dict objectForKey:@"text"]];
}
```

In response to your question about arc4random.

Create an enum so that you can create a switch statement -

```
typedef enum {
    MESSAGE1,
    MESSAGE2,
    MESSAGE3
} messageIDs;
```

then create a random integer and mod it by x so that you get a number btw 0 and x-1. (In this case, since we have 3 things inside the enum, x = 3)

```
int randomValue = arc4random() % 3;
```

then use that random int in a switch statement

```
switch (randomValue) {
    case MESSAGE1:
          [myMessage setText:[dict objectForKey:@"message1"]]; //or [myMessage setText:[array objectAtIndex:MESSAGE1]]
    break;
    case MESSAGE2:
          [myMessage setText:[dict objectForKey:@"message2"]];
    break;
    case MESSAGE3:
          [myMessage setText:[dict objectForKey:@"message3"]];
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

hope this works. I havent tried this before...

Comment: that worked perfectly. thanks so much!

one follow up question - if i wanted to pull a random object from the plist, could i use the arc4random() function? if so, how would that fit in to the [myMessage setText:[dict objectForKey:@"text"]];

thanks again.

Comment: check my answer again, i've updated it to help you with arc4random(). Don't forget to mark this question as answered (if it works!) ;)

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what you tell it to.

Assuming messages.plist contains an array of strings, you can easily get the last item in the array:

```
[myMessage setText:[array lastObject]];
```